# Add CSRF-TOKEN into angularJs 2

Tags: angularjs, django

I am making a website using Django and AngularJs2.

When I created the login form then submit form, Django shows an error:

> forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)

I know Django wants me to add a CSRF token, but I don't know how.

**UPDATE**
this is user.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
   private loggedIn = false;

   constructor(private http: Http) {
   this.loggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
}

login(email:string, password:string) {
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return this.http
  .post(
    '/accounts/login', 
    JSON.stringify({ email, password }), 
    { headers }
  )
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map((res) => {
    if (res.success) {
      /* localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
      this.loggedIn = true; */
      console.log(res);
    }

    return res.success;
  });
 }

logout() {
   localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
   this.loggedIn = false;
 }

isLoggedIn() {
   return this.loggedIn;
 }
}
```

login.component.ts :

```
 // login.component.ts
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { Router } from '@angular/router';

   import { UserService } from './user.service';

   @Component({
       selector: 'login',
       template: `...`
    })
    export class LoginComponent {
        constructor(private userService: UserService, private router:            Router) {}

        onSubmit(email, password) {
            this.userService.login(email, password).subscribe((result) => {
         if (result) {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
          }
       });
      }
   }
```

Comment: not enough code to represent the problem

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax as it should help. Once you take the value send it as extra headers as shown by Sebastian.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def your_view(request):
    pass
```

or if you want to have csrf, send it with your angular

```
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
```

Comment: if i use  @csrf_exempt then DJANGO shows error message :  Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /accounts/login, front end show error message : 
 Response with status: 403 Forbidden for URL: http://localhost:8000/accounts/login

Comment: $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'; I don't know how can use it, where I can place it into file code !????